# my cypress is not working? it says Failed at the paper-dashboard-pro-react@1.1.0 cy script

Tags: node.js, reactjs, json, npm

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! paper-dashboard-pro-react@1.1.0 cy: `start-server-and-test start http://localhost:3000 cy:open`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the paper-dashboard-pro-react@1.1.0 cy script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

i tried npm run cy

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.